# Give Flutter Card an elevation only from the Top

Tags: flutter

I have a Card within an AnimatedContainer as below. I want the Card to have an elevation only at the Top.

I also what the Card to clip to the Animated Container so that there is no margin between the AnimatedContainer and the Card at all. Simply put, they are gummed together if that's a better word.

How can I achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
AnimatedContainer(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: Card( // I want this card to have an elevation only at the top
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Welcome',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 10.0,
                bottom: 15.0,
                left: 25,
                right: 25,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Tap here to get started',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Thanks in anticipation for your input

Comment: When you write `elevation at the top` do you mean just shadow behind the top edge of a container?

Comment: @SzymonKowaliński Yea, exactly. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Can you try adding boxshadow?

Answer (score 1):

## Shadow

1. Firstly set default `elevation` of a `Card` to `0`:

```
elevation: 0,
```

2.And then set some custom shadow to your `AnimatedContainer` in its boxDecoration:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [ // so here your custom shadow goes:
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withAlpha(20), // the color of a shadow, you can adjust it
                        spreadRadius: 3, //also play with this two values to achieve your ideal result
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0, -7), // changes position of shadow, negative value on y-axis makes it appering only on the top of a container
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

So that's it

## Padding

So basically to eliminate the padding between `Card` and `Animated Container` you need to do the following:

- Just set margin of card to zero:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

- Match a border radius of a card and its surrounding container, to avoid some padding around the corner. But you can skip this step if the colour of your `AnimatedContainer` and `Card` is the same. (as in your example) But if this padding would be visible, just define the same borderRadius in your `Card` as in your `AnimatedContainer`.

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
```

## Padding - an alternative solution

*Also, you could possibly eliminate the use of a `Card` widget, cause I don't think it plays a big role in your example. `AnimatedContainer` has very similar properties as a `Card`. In my opinion, `Card` in your example introduces needless complexity. Unless you want to achieve something I didn't get*

- so just delete the `Card` from your widget tree and set backgroundColor of your `AnimatedContainer` in its boxDecoration to white:

  ```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
  //... rest of your code
  ```

### Full code of your example

```
AnimatedContainer(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withAlpha(20),
                        spreadRadius: 3,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0, -7), // changes position of shadow, negative value on y makes it appering on the top
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 0,
                    // I want this card to have an elevation only at the top
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Welcome',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 10.0,
                              bottom: 15.0,
                              left: 25,
                              right: 25,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              'Tap here to get started',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

### Full code an **alternative** solution without use of `Card` at all

```
AnimatedContainer(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withAlpha(
                            20), // the color of a shadow, you can adjust it
                        spreadRadius:
                            3, //also play with this two values to achieve your ideal result
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0,
                            -7), // changes position of shadow, negative value on y-axis makes it appering only on the top of a container
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Welcome',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 10.0,
                            bottom: 15.0,
                            left: 25,
                            right: 25,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Tap here to get started',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```